# Probability question indicator function

Tags: probability

Take the outcomes between 0 and 1. If the probability of a subset of [0,1] is given by the length of the interval, let's call it A, then $$P(A) = \int_a^bdx$$ which makes sense as that just evaluates to $b - a$. But in my textbook, it also says $$= \int_0^1 1_A(x)dx $$ and $1_A(x)$ is some sort of indicator function that equals 1 or 0 if x is in A or not. But how does that make sense? What $x$ am I supposed to put into that indicator function? And if it only equals 0 or 1, how does that in any way give me a probability? The resulting definite integral will be 1 or 0....?

Answer (score 2):

If $A=[a,b]$, then 
$$1_A(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 &\mbox{if}& x\in A=[a,b] \\ 0&&\mbox{otherwise}\end{array} \\  \right.$$

So $\int_0^1 1_A(x)dx=\int_0^a0 dx+\int_a^b1 dx+\int_b^10dx=b-a$.

The desired result!